# Could not download image with s3 getSignedUrl('getObject..) and returns Signature does not match

Tags: node.js, cordova, amazon-s3

I'm relatively new to AWS. All I was trying to do is to upload image from my app to aws S3 and download it to view the image in another page in app. The upload was successful and was able to see the uploaded image in S3. But couldn't download it as it throws the following error.

```
     FileTransferError {body = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we
calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing 
method.</Message><AWSAccessKeyId>AKXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</AWSAccessKeyId>
<StringToSign>GET\n\n\n1469897687\n/huntuploads/uploads/%25222a85a6675d15eeeca5c8b
da6eed4c52e%2522</StringToSign>
<SignatureProvided>cUBhtiA5AGJbj8vl%2FX6xi%2B9BBRY%3D</SignatureProvided>
<StringToSignBytes>47 45 54 0a 0a 0a 31 34 36 39 38 39 37 36 38 37 0a 2f 68 75 6e 
74 66 6f 6f 64 75 70 6c 6f 61 64 73 2f 75 70 6c 6f 61 64 73 2f 25 32 35 32 32 32 
61 38 35 61 36 36 37 35 64 31 35 65 65 65 63 61 35 63 38 62 64 61 36 65 65 64 34 
63 35 32 65 25 32 35 32 32</StringToSignBytes>
<RequestId>CCB513320456EB6B</RequestId>
<HostId>v4c7Ozf911tErWo5dCsL9RNLL78r3rUE6234Z801ZFXuELrji4juDehHmaxnK8t5qMBGcjz90a
I=</HostId></Error>";
        code = 3;
        "http_status" = 403;
        source = "https://huntuploads.s3-us-west-
2.amazonaws.com/uploads/%25222a85a6675d15eeeca5c8bda6eed4c52e%2522?
AWSAccessKeyId=AKXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&Expires=1469897687&Signature=cUBhtiA5AGJbj8vl%
252FX6xi%252B9BBRY%253D";
        target = "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1EB46B25-8BC5-
46C9-BE6B-BF1E120B7627/Documents/%222a85a6675d15eeeca5c8bda6eed4c52e%22";
}
```

Here is the following code for uploading the image which works fine at the server side

```
 var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    AWS.config.update({accessKeyId: 'AXXXXXXXXX......', secretAccessKey: 'XXXXX....'});
    AWS.config.update({region: 'us-west-2'});

var s3 = new AWS.S3( { params: {Bucket: 'huntfooduploads'}});

app.post('/FileUpload', function(req, res, next) {
var fileStream = fs.createReadStream(req.files.file.path);
          var params = {
              'Key': 'uploads/' + req.files.file.name,
              'Body': fileStream,
              'ContentEncoding': 'base64',
              'Content-Type ': 'image/jpeg'
          };

   s3.upload(params, function(err, data) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('after s3 upload====', err, data);
       var imgFileInfo = req.files;
       var imgUploadData = data;
       ....
   }
}
```

Here is the following code used for downloading the image using getSignedUrl for s3 from server side

```
var urlParams = {Bucket: 'huntuploads', Key:'uploads/'+rows[0].MyHunt_FileName};

  // s3 getSigned Url
  s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', urlParams, function(err, url)  {
      if (err) throw callback(err);
       var fullUrl={awsUrl:url};
       res.send(fullUrl);
  })
```

Once I send the fullUrl back to client side which is app, I tried using the following

```
$cordovaFileTransfer.download(encodeURI(itemData[3].awsUrl), targetPath, options, trustHosts)
         .then(function(result) {
           console.log('Success! Download is successful');
            $scope.imgURI = targetPath;
         }, function(err) {
            console.log('Error!!! Download is not successful');
           // Error
         }, function (progress) {
             $timeout(function () {
             $scope.downloadProgress = (progress.loaded / progress.total) * 100;
           });
         });
```

From the app side when I tried to download the image i get the message mentioned above. I tried with adding nx-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-algorithm:AES256 as a header. I need to know the following

1. Is this the correct method of passing the data from server to client (app)
2. If the urlParams for getSigned url is correct. Not sure if I'm missing something or anything to be done.

Can someone advise me in right direction.

Comment: Why is your object key `uploads/"2a85a6675d15eeeca5c8bda6eed4c52e"` with double quotes?  While not technically "wrong," it's unusual, and is contributing to the problem you're experiencing -- which appears to be double-URL-escaping. To pinpoint where the error occurs, I need to understand something else... in the signed URL you are generating, do you see `uploads/%25222a...` or is it just `uploads/%222a...`?

Comment: Hi Michael, Thanks for your response. I also found that the signature is modified  '"uploads/%25222a"' instead of '"uploads/%222a..."' . I'm not sure why. I've even verified the full url which I'm receiving at the client side (app). And in this case I mean "itemData[3].awsUrl" which shows "%222a". But when I pass this as a parameter to $CordovaFileTransfer.download(encodeURI(itemData[3].awsUrl)..)  and execute that, it converts "%222a.." to "/%25222a...". I even tried without encodedURI, just by passing the full URL as a parameter. Even it didn't work out. Not sure if FileTransfer has issues.

Comment: Hi Michael, Based on your suggestion do you think that this is the right way to add the Key while uploading the image `  'Key': 'uploads/' + req.files.file.name. `

Comment: Hi Michael, And on another note, I found that aws url is already encoded, so I've removed  encoded URI() from $cordovaFile Transfer.download() and entered the plain url as a parameter. Unfortunately there still no luck. But I found the following discrepancy still <SignatureProvided>ebJYM3Wbo%2F69l7Dsxm57ZsE84lA%3D</SignatureProvided>  which is correct based the aws url.                                                                                                               And the signature from the source field in the error msg displays Signature=ebJYM3Wbo%252F69l7Dsxm57ZsE84lA%253D.

Comment: Take your signed URL and test it with curl, chrome, firefox.  We need to establish whether it's valid, as generated, and I am inclined to think it is.  `%25` in an aws-v2 signature field in the error response is a dead giveaway of double encoding.  It is impossible for that value to be present in a valid signature. 'uploads/' + ... is probably fine except you seem to have a double quoted string there that you need to clean up first.

Comment: I tried to download another file from s3  `curl -L 'https://huntfooduploads.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/uploads/cdv_photo_001.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=AKXXXXXXX...&Expires=1470141483&Signature=Ac8ZFtb57a4NJekPxaStOJuBzXg%3D' > test.jpg` and it works well without issues. So I think %25 which is some how getting added creates issues with signature. Can you pls advise me for alternative. This is quite taking some time for me. Is it something to do with cordovaa.FileTransfer?

Answer (score 2):

Well I've resolved my self. But thanks for your help Michael and others. The solution is I added the following line as options in one of the

var options = {encodeURI:false};
and then 
cordovaFileTransfer.download(encodeURI(itemData[3].awsUrl), targetPath, options, trustHosts){ ...}

which fixed the issue. Looks like encodeUI is set to true by default which changed the signature.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, getSignedUrl function does not check file exist,

1-Make sure your file URL is correct ( not signed URL).

2-Make sure permission and access to your bucket are correct

Finally, check you date and time of your machine when you call the getSignedUrl function.

Comment: Neither of these suggestions are really applicable, because neither of these problems would cause the `SignatureDoesNotMatch` error -- which only ever means one thing: the signature does not match the credentials and the request, and no further processing was performed. 1. It doesn't matter if the object exists; if that were the problem, the error would be `NoSuchKey` or `AccessDenied`, depending on whether the signing user has permission to list objects.  2.  The error in this case would simply be `AccessDenied`.