# SignatureDoesNotMatch $cordovaFileTransfer

Tags: node.js, cordova, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to upload a video to `Amazon s3` previously recorded with `$cordovaCapture`.

The capture process works correctly, and as a response I get the `object`:

```
[MediaFile]
  0: 
    MediaFileend: 0
    fullPath: "file:/storage/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/VID_20160919_144041.mp4"
    lastModified: null
    lastModifiedDate: 1474288843000
    localURL: "cdvfile://localhost/persistent/DCIM/Camera/VID_20160919_144041.mp4"
    name: "VID_20160919_144041.mp4"
    size: 17098
    start: 0
    type: "video/mp4"
    __proto__: utils.extend.F
  length: 1
  __proto__: Array[0]
```

Then, before I upload the video, I request to my server the [Authenticating URL](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-authenticating-requests.html#signing-request-intro) as it follows:

**nodeJS**

```
getSignedUrl: function (filename, type, callback) {
  if (filename) {
    AWS.config.update({
      accessKeyId: 'my_access_key',
      secretAccessKey: 'my_secret_access_key',
      region: 'my_region'
    });

    var s3 = new AWS.S3();
    s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', {Bucket: 'my_bucket', Key: 'uploads/' + filename, ContentType: type}, function (err, url) {
      if (err) {
        callback(err);
      } else {
        callback(url);
      }
    });
  } else {
    callback('Error');
  }
}
```

That gives me the next endpoint:

```
https://s3-my_region.amazonaws.com/my_bucket/uploads/VID_20160919_144…=video%2Fmp4&Expires=1474289746&Signature=sF67ukPu3oELJXzsmAXCeeEJ%2FE4%3D
```

After I get the `URL` to point my upload, here is where problems are comming:

Having this code:

```
var options = {
  httpMethod: "PUT",
  fileName: name,
  mimeType: type,
  chunkedMode: 'false',
  encodedURI: 'false',
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": type
  }
};

$cordovaFileTransfer.upload(url, videoPath, options)
  .then(function (result) {
    callback(result);
  }, function (err) {
    callback(err);
  }, function (progress) {
    p = progress;
});
```

This is the error that I get:

```
http status: 403
Code: 1
description: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
  <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
  <Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>
  <AWSAccessKeyId>my_access_key</AWSAccessKeyId>
  <StringToSign>
    PUT
    video/mp4
    1474291133
    /my_bucket/uploads/VID_20160919_150347.mp4
  </StringToSign>
  <SignatureProvided>
    nwLEVBOarxi7YwyB4hJ2op4j1ms%253D
  </SignatureProvided>
  <StringToSignBytes>
    50 55 54 0a 0a 76 69 64 65 6f 2f....
  </StringToSignBytes>
  <RequestId>CC29DD761826BAFF</RequestId>
  <HostId>
    OHTLyBaAa29X04msYXqwmvr1Mw90wnPmkxXeU7pTOb9pFwDuuRXDC3AdLNwVIoEHnoUEsceWn24=
  </HostId>
</Error>
```

Sounds like the problem is around the `header`, that doesn't work as expected.

As well, I tried with a second option `code` in my client following directly the documentation of the [cordova-plugin-file-transfer](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer#uploadFile):

```
var options = new FileUploadOptions(),
  ft = new FileTransfer();

options.httpMethod = "PUT";
options.fileName = name;
options.mimeType = type;
options.headers = {
  ContentType: type
};
options.chunkedMode = "false";
options.encodeURI = "false";

ft.upload(videoPath, url, callback, callback, options);
```

with the same response error.

Here I got also problems with `Content-Type`. Even though in the documentation declares like:

```
var headers = {
  "Content-Type": 'video/mp4'
};

options.headers = headers;
```

it was returning me the next error:

```
http status: 501
description: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
  <Code>NotImplemented</Code>
  <Message>
    A header you provided implies functionality that is not implemented
  </Message>
  <Header>Transfer-Encoding</Header>
  <RequestId>231F38AFFBB587C6</RequestId>
  .
  .
  .
</Error>
```

Just as a note, I made it work with a `$http.post` like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39524749/uploading-a-file-to-s3) other post of mine.

**UPDATE**

Investigating much more in the issue, with the `nodeJS` code I wasn't able to upload anything as well, so I just modified the `S3` constructor like this way:

```
s3 = new AWS.S3({
  signatureVersion: 'v4',
  region: "us-west-2"
});
```

After that, checking with `curl` through console like this way:

```
curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" --upload-file "/Users/my_user/Desktop/VID_20160920_233443.mp4" "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/my_bucket/uploads/VID_20160920_233443.mp4?Content-Type=video%2Fmp4&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAJV3UP7LBEKPYMLGA%2F20160921%2Fus-west-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20160921T103723Z&X-Amz-Expires=600&X-Amz-Signature=8463625a45237452280b3dc9cfd89366093f7b78f8c76598ba2240f06c7f20c9&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host%3Bx-amz-acl&x-amz-acl=public-read"
```

the response was successfully:

```
*   Trying 54.231.176.22...
* Connected to s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com (54.231.176.22) port 443 (#0)
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* Server certificate: *.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com
* Server certificate: DigiCert Baltimore CA-2 G2
* Server certificate: Baltimore CyberTrust Root
> PUT /my_bucket/uploads/VID_20160920_233443.mp4?Content-Type=video%2Fmp4&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAJV3UP7LBEKPYMLGA%2F20160921%2Fus-west-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20160921T103723Z&X-Amz-Expires=600&X-Amz-Signature=8463625a45237452280b3dc9cfd89366093f7b78f8c76598ba2240f06c7f20c9&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host%3Bx-amz-acl&x-amz-acl=public-read HTTP/1.1
> Host: s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/octet-stream
> Content-Length: 18964
> Expect: 100-continue
> 
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
* We are completely uploaded and fine
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< x-amz-id-2: moDxOsEISsfqjCILaIsJtl3ncc7UeH4hNNISiJeuH46MrDrHEfVm9EKC5RRkORMilDEE5z7l8cI=
< x-amz-request-id: BC345E2AC71AC019
< Date: Wed, 21 Sep 2016 10:38:05 GMT
< x-amz-expiration: expiry-date="Fri, 23 Sep 2016 00:00:00 GMT", rule-id="Delete bad uploads after 1 day"
< ETag: "7688c487b1ea40c849fdb070cf736b28"
< Content-Length: 0
< Server: AmazonS3
< 
* Connection #0 to host s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com left intact
```

changing the `angular` code like this new one:

```
var options = new FileUploadOptions(),
    ft = new FileTransfer();

options.httpMethod = "PUT";
options.fileKey = "file";
options.fileName = name;
options.mimeType = type;
options.chunkedMode = false;

options.headers = {
  "Content-Type": type,
  "x-amz-acl": 'public-read'
};

ft.upload(videoPath, url, callback(null), callback, options);
```

The problem still comes:

```
An error has occurred: Code = 1
upload error source cdvfile://localhost/persistent/DCIM/Camera/VID_20160921_122323.mp4
upload error target https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/my_bucket/uploads/VID_20160921_122…9e365af3f771c5d&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host%3Bx-amz-acl&x-amz-acl=public-read
http status: 501
description: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>NotImplemented</Code><Message>A header you provided implies functionality that is not implemented</Message><Header>Transfer-Encoding</Header><RequestId>D646593FD109C0F8</RequestId><HostId>wVmGWPAAWdmSXdq5N/eO7ihqHk0GoMlXNe6k9sAyyEz55Q4k2gGgkgsgyXkh8xsxUDlmzQdAIPQ=</HostId></Error>
```

Here I include my `FileUploadOptions()`:

```
chunkedMode: false
fileKey: "file"
fileName: "VID_20160921_125152.mp4"
headers: Object
  Content-Type: "video/mp4"
  x-amz-acl: "public-read"
  __proto__: Object
httpMethod: "PUT"
mimeType: "video/mp4"
params: null
```

**UPDATE 2**

Trying directly with the `$cordovaFileTransfer` plugin from [ngCordova](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/fileTransfer/), I get another error:

```
"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>AuthorizationQueryParametersError</Code><Message>Error parsing the X-Amz-Credential parameter; the Credential is mal-formed; expecting "&lt;YOUR-AKID&gt;/YYYYMMDD/REGION/SERVICE/aws4_request".</Message><RequestId>C863350E96804F5C</RequestId><HostId>7TmXBDlsGNvDmLFKgLePTMAg+Onf8y1ZPTEWmbdHPAyWHFIdt1+5J7U3H8Ygnf3sebMRpRNdxXA=</HostId></Error>"
```

**UPDATE 3**

To clarify everything as much as possible I've deployed a [github](https://github.com/DevStarlight/upload_record_s3_presigned_url) with all the backend/frontend in which I'm working.

Thanks once again.

**UPDATE 4**

Thanks to the help of daserge, I could get the headers of my PUT. Here bellow I paste the result:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
x-amz-request-id    3F686CFD09B5C6DD
x-amz-id-2  KDrmvzhnrWfLB+Tdttg88MaPVOp2LOBAhwEqiBR0XdMpaje3lRsiM6mHfjv5ULzD7GweiT9C2T0=
Content-Type    application/xml
Date    Sat, 24 Sep 2016 17:00:03 GMT
Server  AmazonS3
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
Proxy-Connection    Close

PUT /my_bucket/uploads/VID_20160924_190000.mp4?Content-Type=video%252Fmp4&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAJV3UP7LBEKPYMLGA%252F20160924%252Fus-west-2%252Fs3%252Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20160924T170002Z&X-Amz-Expires=600&X-Amz-Signature=ca3c992290bdf51e14bab6d67e4c520b280368bdd2a0274b552dc3e975f55c9d&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host%253Bx-amz-acl&x-amz-acl=public-read HTTP/1.1
Content-Type    application/octet-stream
Content-Length  56116
User-Agent  Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 5.0; Aquaris E5 HD Build/LRX21M)
Host    s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com
Connection  Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding gzip
```

Then I realiced there were 2 parameters wrong:

```
Content-Type: application/xml
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

As well, I've realiced about encoding. It sould be `%2F` and it's coming like `%252F`.

Which is strange because the way I'm using the params seems to be right:

```
options = {
  fileKey: 'file',
  fileName: name,
  chunkedMode: false,
  httpMethod: 'PUT',
  mimeType: "application/octet-stream",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream"
  }
};

$cordovaFileTransfer.upload(server, filePath, options)
  .then(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
  }, function (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }, function (progress) {
    console.log(progress);
  });
```

as well, thanks to bvakiti I've realiced there is an error message because I'm sending the video to an `https`. I'm trying `http`.

Comment: Have you tried analyzing the request from Cordova with Fiddler?

Comment: I've been trying with `charles`, as a proxy to intercept trafic, but it didn't work since I'm inside `adb`. I'll give it a try to this new tool since I didn't know about it.

Comment: Here is a help link for Fiddler + Android: http://www.cantoni.org/2013/11/06/capture-android-web-traffic-fiddler

Comment: I'm just trying it! sounds useful since the only way I was debugging the app was through `chrome://inspect/#devices`

Comment: what is the videopath that you are sending in the above cordovafileTransfer method

Comment: the `localURL: "cdvfile://localhost/persistent/DCIM/Camera/VID_20160919_144041.mp4"` according to what the plugin says https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer#backwards-compatibility-notes

Comment: @DevStarlight Suggest you to look at this link - https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/86 for krilnon's comment which says adding extra header caused the issue.

Comment: I'm just taking a look since there are many combinations of people reporting problems with the same thing. Thanks.

Comment: Regarding double encode issue by ngCordova: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38684415/could-not-download-image-with-s3-getsignedurlgetobject-and-returns-signatur (try adding `encodeURI: false` to options)

Comment: Yeah I was writing the final result since I found the solution and was related to this issue. I hope as well, this post help people doing the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there is a conflict between the endpoint you get from `AWS` and the way you use `$cordovaFileTransfer`.

When you get the endpoint with `s3.getSignedUrl` in your server, only the params of the the response URL are encoded (the base URL keeps non-encoded).

When you use `$cordovaFileTransfer` That function encodes again the params, that's why you see that `%252F` which match to `//`.

There are 3 options:

- Instead, before your `$cordovaFileTransfer` calling, decode the params

  ```
  var host = server.split('?')[0] + '?' + decodeURIComponent(server.split('?')[1]);
  ```
- Use `options.params` as described in the [documentation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer)

The option `encodeURI: false` suggested in other help comments didn't work for me

Hope it helps.

Comment: Actually this is a real solution to my question, although the first option could be more efficient. Second option is just recommended if you just want to add some extra params when you are generating the `endpoint` on `AWS` and great for understanding how signatures work in.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is some problem with derivation of Access Key from AWS.

Try Using this:

```
function getSignatureKey(key, dateStamp, regionName, serviceName) {
    var kDate= Crypto.HMAC(Crypto.SHA256, dateStamp, "AWS4" + key, { asBytes: true})
    var kRegion= Crypto.HMAC(Crypto.SHA256, regionName, kDate, { asBytes: true });
    var kService=Crypto.HMAC(Crypto.SHA256, serviceName, kRegion, { asBytes: true });
    var kSigning= Crypto.HMAC(Crypto.SHA256, "aws4_request", kService, { asBytes: true });

    return kSigning;
}
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-examples.html#signature-v4-examples-jscript

I also found an old blog if it helps:

http://coenraets.org/blog/2013/09/how-to-upload-pictures-from-a-phonegap-app-to-amazon-s3/

Comment: Reading the document you passed to me, it says: 
`you do not have to manually perform the steps of deriving a signing key and adding authentication information to a request.` by using the `aws-sdk`.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a problem with uploading with an empty body / empty Content-Length

Have a look at this thread:
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/15

Comment: Even though this thread is referencing an uploading on the server side (which is not my objective). I tried setting on the client side that `Content-Length`, since I have the param, but It kept giving the same error code (501).

Comment: At this point, have you been able to upload anything at all using any mean to your bucket? More precisely, the aws cli https://aws.amazon.com/cli/

Comment: Yes, If I use `$http.post` that works and it places correctly to the folder.

Comment: Can you review this (maybe again if you already read though it): http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-query-string-auth.html

I can't verify but the signature you provide (nwLEVBOarxi7YwyB4hJ2op4j1ms%253D) seems a bit odd according to the docs

Comment: That signature about what you talk was modified on purpose just to protect my credentials & other stuff. I'm actually checking once again that `AWS` post you provided me ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123984/discussion-between-devstarlight-and-kuzyn).

Answer (score 0):

After updating your AWS bucket configuration do not pass the parameters when creating S3 object. Try below code.

```
   // make managed upload
    var upload = new AWS.S3.ManagedUpload({
        params: metadata
    });

    var s3Head = new AWS.S3();
```

Make changes in routes/endpoints.js.

Comment: is that solution oriented for a direct uploading after the signing on the server side? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3/ManagedUpload.html#constructor-property What I'm looking for is a client side upload by requesting a `signedURL` previously to the server.

Answer (score 0):

I faced an issue of error code 1 during fileTransfer and giving html elements as response.

Problem is with SSL connection. Try giving http and not https in the server url, It will work fine.
But when it comes to authentication you will have change in backend. There is no problem with cordovaFileTransfer.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @DevStarlight Did you check with this?